# How to write a common code for inserting data in android's Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

For inserting into sqlite presently I have to follow these steps:

- Create contentValues i.e. `ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();`
- Put column_name and Value
- lastly, call `sqLiteDatabase.insert(DATABASE_NAME,null,contentValues)`

Problem is only in step 2,we have manually `Columnname` and `Columnvalue` for n number of times assuming I have n Columns to persist.

So, I wrote the following method thinking I can reuse it:

```
public void insert(Map tableMap){

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        Iterator tableMapIterator = tableMap.entrySet().iterator();

        while(tableMapIterator.hasNext()){
            Map.Entry mapEntry = (Map.Entry)tableMapIterator.next();
            contentValues.put((String)mapEntry.getKey(), mapEntry.getValue());
        }
       sqLiteDatabase.insert(DATABASE_NAME,null,contentValues)

    }
```

But the problem is that when I call `mapEntry.getValue()`, the return type is Object for which `contentValues.put` is not defined.

So, can anyone tell me any workaround so that I can use the above approach efficiently to do the data insertion.

**NOTE** : *I want to write method so that I can use it for all data types in SQLITE.*

Comment: `ContentValues` is already such a map. Adding a wrapper around it does not really make code simpler.

Comment: There is a funny trick using Parcelhttp://njzk2.wordpress.com/2013/05/31/map-to-contentvalues-abusing-parcelable/

Comment: @laalto : Ya you are correct that `ContentValues` is already a map.But it is a pain to type all column names and its values every time.Rather I was thinking to pass a map with column_name as key and respective data as value on which we can iterate and persist.this will enable me to reuse the insert method throughout the application.

Comment: So, how do you plan to populate and maintain that map? Equal burden is just shifted to another place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The objects that will access your ContentMap will be verified by this method [DatabaseUtils.getTypeOfObject()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/database/DatabaseUtils.java#DatabaseUtils.getTypeOfObject%28java.lang.Object%29)

Therefore, if you put anything in your ContentValue that is not one of the expected type, it will be assumed to be a String, and in [bindArguments()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteConnection.java#SQLiteConnection.bindArguments%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.PreparedStatement%2Cjava.lang.Object%5B%5D%29), `toString()` will be called on it.

Now, assuming that all your object are either recognized valid types, or have sufficient String representation (for instance, a `File` object would give its path, which is sufficient to recreate it when you extract it from the database), there are ways to put an arbitrary Map in a ContentValue.

The trivial way is to use reflection to access the [internal map](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/content/ContentValues.java#ContentValues.0mValues), which is consistently named `mValues` across all versions of android.

Another, shorter (but slower) and clearer way, I find, is to use the `Parcel` mechanism. Indeed, [ContentValue.writeToParcel](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/content/ContentValues.java#ContentValues.writeToParcel%28android.os.Parcel%2Cint%29) only writes the internal map.

The entire code is here:

```
Parcel parcel = obtain();
parcel.writeMap(map);
parcel.setDataPosition(0);
ContentValues values = ContentValues.CREATOR.createFromParcel(parcel);
```

Detailed explanation on my blog : http://njzk2.wordpress.com/2013/05/31/map-to-contentvalues-abusing-parcelable/

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure if i get your question but i will try my best.

1) You can use some kind of already written ORM. - It can automatically detect field types.

2) You can write your own simple ORM to handle situations like this. When i want to automatically add object to DB, i inherit this table object from GenericTableObject, which has methods like getFieldsValues, getFieldsTypes etc... With help of these methods, it is fully automated.

You will probably spend a few hours by writing this generic table object but it is usefull. - It is all about java reflection.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
public void addEntity(EntityClass e) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("Name",e.getmProductName());
        values.put("Price",e.getmProductPrice());
        values.put("Date",e.getmPurchaseDate());
        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_Accounts, null, values);
        Log.d("insert", "success");
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Info added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        db.close(); // Closing database connection




    }
```